# How to use the actual feature names instead of "X" in scikit-learn DecisionTreeRegressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I suppose this is possible since in the def of `fit` function [it says](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.fit):

> X : array-like, shape = [n_samples, n_features]

Now I have,

[image]

I can certainly generate a string representation of the decision tree then replace `X[]` with actual feature names. But I wonder if the `fit` function could directly take feature names as part of inputs? I tried the following format for each sample

- [1, 2, "feature_1", "feature_2"]
- [[1, 2], ["feature_1", "feature_2"]]

but neither worked. What does that `shape` mean? Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `fit` function itself doesn't support anything like that. However, you can draw the decision tree, including feature labels, with the [`export_graphviz`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html) member function. (Isn't this how you generated the tree above?). Essentially, you'd do something like this:

```
iris = load_iris()
t = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
fitted_tree = t.fit(iris.data, iris.targets)
outfile = tree.export_graphviz(fitted_tree, out_file='filename.dot', feature_names=iris.feature_names)
outfile.close()
```

This will produce a 'dot' file, which graphviz (which must be installed separately) can then "render" into a traditional image format (postscript, png, etc.) For example, to make a png file, you'd run:

```
dot -Tpng filename.dot > filename.png
```

The dot file itself is a plain-text format and fairly self-explanatory. If you wanted to tweak the text, a simple find-replace in the text editor of your choice would work. There are also python modules for directly interacting with graphviz and its files. [PyDot](https://code.google.com/p/pydot/) seems to be pretty popular, but there are others too.

---

The `shape` reference in `fit`'s documentation just refers to the layout of `X`, the training data matrix. Specifically, it expects the first index to vary over training examples, while the 2nd index refers to features. For example, suppose your data's `shape` is (150, 4), as is the case for `iris.data`. The `fit` function will interpret it as containing 150 training examples, each of which consists of four values.

Answer (score 2):

`X` should be a 2 dimensional numpy `ndarray` where each row corresponds to a sample and each column represents the values of a feature. That `shape` refers to the number of rows and columns of the feature data `X`.

An example of a valid `X` which contains 3 samples and 2 features:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[2,2],[2,0],[0,2]])
y = np.array([0,1,1])
print X.shape # Output (2,2)
```

where the first sample has value 1 and 2 for the first and second feature respectively.

If you have a representation of the feature data in a list of `dict` (each `dict` corresponds to a single sample) like so

```
D = [
 {'feature1': 2, 'feature2': 2},
 {'feature1': 2, 'feature2': 0},
 {'feature1': 0, 'feature2': 2}
]
```

then you can use [`DictVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html) to produce the matrix `X`:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
v = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
X = v.fit_transform(D)
```